# Insertar contenido de un JSON en un select usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Buen día,

Estoy teniendo un problema con recorrer un archivo JSON para insertar ciertos datos en una etiqueta Select de HTML. Estoy usando este archivo JSON:

```
{
    "provincias": {
        "1": {
            "nombre": "San José",
            "cantones": {
                "01": {
                    "nombre": "Central",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Carmen",
                        "02": "Merced",
                        "03": "Hospital",
                        "04": "Catedral",
                        "05": "Zapote",
                        "06": "San Francisco De Dos Rios",
                        "07": "Uruca",
                        "08": "Mata Redonda",
                        "09": "Pavas",
                        "10": "Hatillo",
                        "11": "San Sebastián"
                    }
                },
                "02": {
                    "nombre": "Escazú",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Escazú",
                        "02": "San Antonio",
                        "03": "San Rafael"
                    }
                },
                "03": {
                    "nombre": "Desamparados",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Desamparados",
                        "02": "San Miguel",
                        "03": "San Juan De Dios",
                        "04": "San Rafael Arriba",
                        "05": "San Rafael Abajo",
                        "06": "San Antonio",
                        "07": "Frailes",
                        "08": "Patarra",
                        "09": "San Cristobal",
                        "10": "Rosario",
                        "11": "Damas",
                        "12": "Gravilias",
                        "13": "Los Guido"
                    }
                },
                "04": {
                    "nombre": "Puriscal",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Santiago",
                        "02": "Mercedes Sur",
                        "03": "Barbacoas",
                        "04": "Grifo Alto",
                        "05": "San Rafael",
                        "06": "Candelarita",
                        "07": "Desamparaditos",
                        "08": "San Antonio",
                        "09": "Chires"
                    }
                },
                "05": {
                    "nombre": "Tarrazú",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Marcos",
                        "02": "San Lorenzo",
                        "03": "San Carlos"
                    }
                },
                "06": {
                    "nombre": "Aserrí",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Aserrí",
                        "02": "Tarbaca",
                        "03": "Vuelta De Jorco",
                        "04": "San Gabriel",
                        "05": "Legua",
                        "06": "Monterrey",
                        "07": "Salitrillos"
                    }
                },
                "07": {
                    "nombre": "Mora",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Colón",
                        "02": "Guayabo",
                        "03": "Tabarcia",
                        "04": "Piedras Negras",
                        "05": "Picagres",
                        "06": "Jaris"
                    }
                },
                "08": {
                    "nombre": "Goicoechea",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Guadalupe",
                        "02": "San Francisco",
                        "03": "Calle Blancos",
                        "04": "Mata De Platano",
                        "05": "Ipís",
                        "06": "Rancho Redondo",
                        "07": "Purral"
                    }
                },
                "09": {
                    "nombre": "Santa Ana",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Santa Ana",
                        "02": "Salitral",
                        "03": "Pozos",
                        "04": "Uruca",
                        "05": "Piedades",
                        "06": "Brasil"
                    }
                },
                "10": {
                    "nombre": "Alajuelita",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Alajuelita",
                        "02": "San Josecito",
                        "03": "San Antonio",
                        "04": "Concepción",
                        "05": "San Felipe"
                    }
                },
                "11": {
                    "nombre": "Vázquez De Coronado",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Isidro",
                        "02": "San Rafael",
                        "03": "Dulce Nombre De Jesus",
                        "04": "Patalillo",
                        "05": "Cascajal"
                    }
                },
                "12": {
                    "nombre": "Acosta",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Ignacio",
                        "02": "Guaitil",
                        "03": "Palmichal",
                        "04": "Cangrejal",
                        "05": "Sabanillas"
                    }
                },
                "13": {
                    "nombre": "Tibás",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Juan",
                        "02": "Cinco Esquinas",
                        "03": "Anselmo Llorente",
                        "04": "Leon XII",
                        "05": "Colima"
                    }
                },
                "14": {
                    "nombre": "Moravia",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Vicente",
                        "02": "San Jeronimo",
                        "03": "La Trinidad"
                    }
                },
                "15": {
                    "nombre": "Montes De Oca",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Pedro",
                        "02": "Sabanilla",
                        "03": "Mercedes",
                        "04": "San Rafael"
                    }
                },
                "16": {
                    "nombre": "Turrubares",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Pablo",
                        "02": "San Pedro",
                        "03": "San Juan De Mata",
                        "04": "San Luis",
                        "05": "Carara"
                    }
                },
                "17": {
                    "nombre": "Dota",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Santa María",
                        "02": "Jardin",
                        "03": "Copey"
                    }
                },
                "18": {
                    "nombre": "Curridabat",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Curridabat",
                        "02": "Granadilla",
                        "03": "Sanchez",
                        "04": "Tirrases"
                    }
                },
                "19": {
                    "nombre": "Pérez Zeledón",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Isidro De El General",
                        "02": "El General",
                        "03": "Daniel Flores",
                        "04": "Rivas",
                        "05": "San Pedro",
                        "06": "Platanares",
                        "07": "Pejibaye",
                        "08": "Cajon",
                        "09": "Baru",
                        "10": "Rio Nuevo",
                        "11": "Páramo"
                    }
                },
                "20": {
                    "nombre": "León Cortés Castro",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Pablo",
                        "02": "San Andres",
                        "03": "Llano Bonito",
                        "04": "San Isidro",
                        "05": "Santa Cruz",
                        "06": "San Antonio"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "nombre": "Alajuela",
            "cantones": {
                "01": {
                    "nombre": "Central",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Alajuela",
                        "02": "San José",
                        "03": "Carrizal",
                        "04": "San Antonio",
                        "05": "Guácima",
                        "06": "San Isidro",
                        "07": "Sabanilla",
                        "08": "San Rafael",
                        "09": "Rio Segundo",
                        "10": "Desamparados",
                        "11": "Turrucares",
                        "12": "Tambor",
                        "13": "Garita",
                        "14": "Sarapiquí"
                    }
                },
                "02": {
                    "nombre": "San Ramón",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Ramón",
                        "02": "Santiago",
                        "03": "San Juan",
                        "04": "Piedades Norte",
                        "05": "Piedades Sur",
                        "06": "San Rafael",
                        "07": "San Isidro",
                        "08": "Angeles",
                        "09": "Alfaro",
                        "10": "Volio",
                        "11": "Concepción",
                        "12": "Zapotal",
                        "13": "Peñas Blancas"
                    }
                },
                "03": {
                    "nombre": "Grecia",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Grecia",
                        "02": "San Isidro",
                        "03": "San José",
                        "04": "San Roque",
                        "05": "Tacares",
                        "06": "Rio Cuarto",
                        "07": "Puente De Piedra",
                        "08": "Bolivar"
                    }
                },
                "04": {
                    "nombre": "San Mateo",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Mateo",
                        "02": "Desmonte",
                        "03": "Jesús María",
                        "04": "Labrador"
                    }
                },
                "05": {
                    "nombre": "Atenas",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Atenas",
                        "02": "Jesús",
                        "03": "Mercedes",
                        "04": "San Isidro",
                        "05": "Concepción",
                        "06": "San José",
                        "07": "Santa Eulalia",
                        "08": "Escobal"
                    }
                },
                "06":{
                    "nombre": "Naranjo",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Naranjo",
                        "02": "San Miguel",
                        "03": "San José",
                        "04": "Cirrí Sur",
                        "05": "San Jerónimo",
                        "06": "San Juan",
                        "07": "El Rosario",
                        "08": "Palmitos"
                    }
                },
                "07": {
                    "nombre": "Palmares",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Palmares",
                        "02": "Zaragoza",
                        "03": "Buenos Aires",
                        "04": "Santiago",
                        "05": "Candelaria",
                        "06": "Esquipulas",
                        "07": "La Granja"
                    }
                },
                "08": {
                    "nombre": "Poás",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Pedro",
                        "02": "San Juan",
                        "03": "San Rafael",
                        "04": "Carrillos",
                        "05": "Sabana Redonda"
                    }
                },
                "09": {
                    "nombre": "Orotina",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Orotina",
                        "02": "El Mastate",
                        "03": "Hacienda Vieja",
                        "04": "Coyolar",
                        "05": "La Ceiba"
                    }
                },
                "10": {
                    "nombre": "San Carlos",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Quesada",
                        "02": "Florencia",
                        "03": "Buenavista",
                        "04": "Aguas Zarcas",
                        "05": "Venecia",
                        "06": "Pital",
                        "07": "La Fortuna",
                        "08": "La Tigra",
                        "09": "La Palmera",
                        "10": "Venado",
                        "11": "Cutris",
                        "12": "Monterrey",
                        "13": "Pocosol"
                    }
                },
                "11": {
                    "nombre": "Zarcero",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Zarcero",
                        "02": "Laguna",
                        "03": "Tapesco",
                        "04": "Guadalupe",
                        "05": "Palmira",
                        "06": "Zapote",
                        "07": "Brisas"
                    }
                },
                "12": {
                    "nombre": "Sarchí",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Sarchí Norte",
                        "02": "Sarchí Sur",
                        "03": "Toro Amarillo",
                        "04": "San Pedro",
                        "05": "Rodriguez"
                    }
                },
                "13": {
                    "nombre": "Upala",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Upala",
                        "02": "Aguas Claras",
                        "03": "San José o Pizote",
                        "04": "Bijagua",
                        "05": "Delicias",
                        "06": "Dos Rios",
                        "07": "Yolillal",
                        "08": "Canalete"
                    }
                },
                "14": {
                    "nombre": "Los Chiles",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Los Chiles",
                        "02": "Caño Negro",
                        "03": "El Amparo",
                        "04": "San Jorge"
                    }
                },
                "15": {
                    "nombre": "Guatuso",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Rafael",
                        "02": "Buenavista",
                        "03": "Cote",
                        "04": "Katira"
                    }
                },
                "16": {
                    "nombre": "Río Cuarto",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Río Cuarto"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "nombre": "Cartago",
            "cantones": {
                "01": {
                    "nombre": "Central",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Oriental",
                        "02": "Occidental",
                        "03": "Carmen",
                        "04": "San Nicolás",
                        "05": "Aguacaliente o San Francisco",
                        "06": "Guadalupe o Arenilla",
                        "07": "Corralillo",
                        "08": "Tierra Blanca",
                        "09": "Dulce Nombre",
                        "10": "Llano Grande",
                        "11": "Quebradilla"
                    }
                },
                "02": {
                    "nombre": "Paraíso",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Paraiso",
                        "02": "Santiago",
                        "03": "Orosi",
                        "04": "Cachí",
                        "05": "Llanos de Santa Lucía"
                    }
                },
                "03": {
                    "nombre": "La Unión",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Tres Rios",
                        "02": "San Diego",
                        "03": "San Juan",
                        "04": "San Rafael",
                        "05": "Concepción",
                        "06": "Dulce Nombre",
                        "07": "San Ramón",
                        "08": "Rio Azul"
                    }
                },
                "04": {
                    "nombre": "Jiménez",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Juan Viñas",
                        "02": "Tucurrique",
                        "03": "Pejibaye"
                    }
                },
                "05": {
                    "nombre": "Turrialba",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Turrialba",
                        "02": "La Suiza",
                        "03": "Peralta",
                        "04": "Santa Cruz",
                        "05": "Santa Teresita",
                        "06": "Pavones",
                        "07": "Tuis",
                        "08": "Tayutic",
                        "09": "Santa Rosa",
                        "10": "Tres Equis",
                        "11": "La Isabel",
                        "12": "Chirripó"
                    }
                },
                "06": {
                    "nombre": "Alvarado",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Pacayas",
                        "02": "Cervantes",
                        "03": "Capellades"
                    }
                },
                "07": {
                    "nombre": "Oreamuno",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Rafael",
                        "02": "Cot",
                        "03": "Potrero Cerrado",
                        "04": "Cipreses",
                        "05": "Santa Rosa"
                    }
                },
                "08": {
                    "nombre": "El Guarco",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "El Tejar",
                        "02": "San Isidro",
                        "03": "Tobosi",
                        "04": "Patio De Agua"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "4": {
            "nombre": "Heredia",
            "cantones": {
                "01": {
                    "nombre": "Central",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Heredia",
                        "02": "Mercedes",
                        "03": "San Francisco",
                        "04": "Ulloa",
                        "05": "Varablanca"
                    }
                },
                "02": {
                    "nombre": "Barva",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Barva",
                        "02": "San Pedro",
                        "03": "San Pablo",
                        "04": "San Roque",
                        "05": "Santa Lucía",
                        "06": "San José de la Montaña"
                    }
                },
                "03": { 
                    "nombre": "Santo Domingo",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Santo Domingo",
                        "02": "San Vicente",
                        "03": "San Miguel",
                        "04": "Paracito",
                        "05": "Santo Tomás",
                        "06": "Santa Rosa",
                        "07": "Tures",
                        "08": "Para"
                    }
                },
                "04": { 
                    "nombre": "Santa Barbara",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Santa Bárbara",
                        "02": "San Pedro",
                        "03": "San Juan",
                        "04": "Jesús",
                        "05": "Santo Domingo",
                        "06": "Puraba"
                    }
                },
                "05": { 
                    "nombre": "San Rafael",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Rafael",
                        "02": "San Josecito",
                        "03": "Santiago",
                        "04": "Los Ángeles",
                        "05": "Concepción"
                    }
                },
                "06": { 
                    "nombre": "San Isidro",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Isidro",
                        "02": "San José",
                        "03": "Concepción",
                        "04": "San Francisco"
                    }
                },
                "07": { 
                    "nombre": "Belén",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Antonio",
                        "02": "La Ribera",
                        "03": "La Asuncion"
                    }
                },
                "08": { 
                    "nombre": "Flores",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Joaquín",
                        "02": "Barrantes",
                        "03": "Llorente"
                    }
                },
                "09": { 
                    "nombre": "San Pablo",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Pablo",
                        "02": "Rincon De Sabanilla"
                    }
                },
                "10": { 
                    "nombre": "Sarapiquí",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Puerto Viejo",
                        "02": "La Virgen",
                        "03": "Las Horquetas",
                        "04": "Llanuras Del Gaspar",
                        "05": "Cureña"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "5": {
            "nombre": "Guanacaste",
            "cantones": {
                "01": {
                    "nombre": "Liberia",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Liberia",
                        "02": "Cañas Dulces",
                        "03": "Mayorga",
                        "04": "Nacascolo",
                        "05": "Curubande"
                    }
                },
                "02": {
                    "nombre": "Nicoya",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Nicoya",
                        "02": "Mansión",
                        "03": "San Antonio",
                        "04": "Quebrada Honda",
                        "05": "Sámara",
                        "06": "Nosara",
                        "07": "Belén De Nosarita"
                    }
                },
                "03": {
                    "nombre": "Santa Cruz",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Santa Cruz",
                        "02": "Bolson",
                        "03": "Veintisiete de Abril",
                        "04": "Tempate",
                        "05": "Cartagena",
                        "06": "Cuajiniquil",
                        "07": "Diria",
                        "08": "Cabo Velas",
                        "09": "Tamarindo"
                    }
                },
                "04": {
                    "nombre": "Bagaces",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Bagaces",
                        "02": "La Fortuna",
                        "03": "Mogote",
                        "04": "Rio Naranjo"
                    }
                },
                "05": {
                    "nombre": "Carrillo",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Filadelfia",
                        "02": "Palmira",
                        "03": "Sardinal",
                        "04": "Belen"
                    }
                },
                "06": {
                    "nombre": "Cañas",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Cañas",
                        "02": "Palmira",
                        "03": "San Miguel",
                        "04": "Bebedero",
                        "05": "Porozal"
                    }
                },
                "07": {
                    "nombre": "Abangares",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Las Juntas",
                        "02": "Sierra",
                        "03": "San Juan",
                        "04": "Colorado"
                    }
                },
                "08": {
                    "nombre": "Tilarán",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Tilarán",
                        "02": "Quebrada Grande",
                        "03": "Tronadora",
                        "04": "Santa Rosa",
                        "05": "Líbano",
                        "06": "Tierras Morenas",
                        "07": "Arenal"
                    }
                },
                "09": {
                    "nombre": "Nandayure",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Carmona",
                        "02": "Santa Rita",
                        "03": "Zapotal",
                        "04": "San Pablo",
                        "05": "Porvenir",
                        "06": "Bejuco"
                    }
                },
                "10": {
                    "nombre": "La Cruz",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "La Cruz",
                        "02": "Santa Cecilia",
                        "03": "La Garita",
                        "04": "Santa Elena"
                    }
                },
                "11": {
                    "nombre": "Hojancha",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Hojancha",
                        "02": "Monte Romo",
                        "03": "Puerto Carrillo",
                        "04": "Huacas"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "6": {
            "nombre": "Puntarenas",
            "cantones": {
                "01": {
                    "nombre": "Central",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Puntarenas",
                        "02": "Pitahaya",
                        "03": "Chomes",
                        "04": "Lepanto",
                        "05": "Paquera",
                        "06": "Manzanillo",
                        "07": "Guacimal",
                        "08": "Barranca",
                        "09": "Monte Verde",
                        "10": "Isla Del Coco",
                        "11": "Cóbano",
                        "12": "Chacarita",
                        "13": "Chira",
                        "14": "Acapulco",
                        "15": "El Roble",
                        "16": "Arancibia"
                    }
                },
                "02": {
                    "nombre": "Esparza",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Espíritu Santo",
                        "02": "San Juan Grande",
                        "03": "Macacona",
                        "04": "San Rafael",
                        "05": "San Jerónimo"
                    }
                },
                "03": {
                    "nombre": "Buenos Aires",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Buenos Aires",
                        "02": "Volcán",
                        "03": "Potrero Grande",
                        "04": "Boruca",
                        "05": "Pilas",
                        "06": "Colinas",
                        "07": "Changuena",
                        "08": "Biolley",
                        "09": "Brunka"
                    }
                },
                "04": {
                    "nombre": "Montes De Oro",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Miramar",
                        "02": "La Unión",
                        "03": "San Isidro"
                    }
                },
                "05": {
                    "nombre": "Osa",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Puerto Cortés",
                        "02": "Palmar",
                        "03": "Sierpe",
                        "04": "Bahía Ballena",
                        "05": "Piedras Blancas",
                        "06": "Bahía Drake"
                    }
                },
                "06": {
                    "nombre": "Quepos",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Quepos",
                        "02": "Savegre",
                        "03": "Naranjito"
                    }
                },
                "07": {
                    "nombre": "Golfito",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Golfito",
                        "02": "Puerto Jiménez",
                        "03": "Guaycara",
                        "04": "Pavón"
                    }
                },
                "08": {
                    "nombre": "Coto Brus",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "San Vito",
                        "02": "Sabalito",
                        "03": "Aguabuena",
                        "04": "Limoncito",
                        "05": "Pittier"
                    }
                },
                "09": {
                    "nombre": "Parrita",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Parrita"
                    }
                },
                "10": {
                    "nombre": "Corredores",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Corredor",
                        "02": "La Cuesta",
                        "03": "Canoas",
                        "04": "Laurel"
                    }
                },
                "11": {
                    "nombre": "Garabito",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Jacó",
                        "02": "Tárcoles"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "7": {
            "nombre": "Limón",
            "cantones": {
                "01": {
                    "nombre": "Central",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Limón",
                        "02": "Valle La Estrella",
                        "03": "Rio Blanco",
                        "04": "Matama"
                    }
                },
                "02": {
                    "nombre": "Pococí",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Guapiles",
                        "02": "Jiménez",
                        "03": "Rita",
                        "04": "Roxana",
                        "05": "Cariari",
                        "06": "Colorado",
                        "07": "La Colonia"
                    }
                },
                "03": {
                    "nombre": "Siquirres",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Siquirres",
                        "02": "Pacuarito",
                        "03": "Florida",
                        "04": "Germania",
                        "05": "El Cairo",
                        "06": "Alegría"
                    }
                },
                "04": { 
                    "nombre": "Talamanca",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Bratsi",
                        "02": "Sixaola",
                        "03": "Cahuita",
                        "04": "Telire"
                    }
                },
                "05": {
                    "nombre": "Matina",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Matina",
                        "02": "Batán",
                        "03": "Carrandi"
                    }
                },
                "06": {
                    "nombre": "Guácimo",
                    "distritos": {
                        "01": "Guácimo",
                        "02": "Mercedes",
                        "03": "Pocora",
                        "04": "Rio Jiménez",
                        "05": "Duacari"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y mi intención es extraer los datos de nombre dentro de cada provincia, luego obtener los nombres dentro de cada cantón y por último los nombres dentro de cada distrito. Haciendo y buscando he llegado hasta este código:

```
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/josuenoel/80daca657b71bc1cfd95a4e27d547abe/raw/5c615419196ed40a3dbdff69cb3d9719b1d6bb1e/provincias_cantones_distritos_costa_rica.json';

const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        // console.log("-------- Texto -------");
        // console.log(this.responseText);
        let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(datos);

        const provincias = [];

        Object.keys(datos.provincias).forEach(element => {
           provincias.push(element);
        })
        console.log(provincias);
    }
}
```

El cual me tira un arreglo con el contenido de los números del 1 al 7 que es lo que esta dentro de provincias. Aquí supongo que debería entrar a cada número para obtener los datos del nombre de la provincia y así sucesivamente pero estoy bloqueado y no se como pasar de ahí. Intente hacer un forEach dentro del primer forEach pero me indica que el valor es indefinido.

Gracias por la atención

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera en la que están los datos en el objeto que obtienes es *poco amigable* para el proceso, pues tiene la información en miembros/propiedades de objetos, que están anidados.

Cuándo tienes un objeto así, usualmente puedes navegarlo, pero dado que está usando números para nombrar estos miembros, se complica un poco más.

Mi sugerencia es que primero traslades la información a un arreglo, dónde cada objeto contiene la información de una provincia que, a su vez, tiene un arreglo con los cantones y cada cantón tiene un arreglo con los distritos.

Para hacer la *conversión*, puedes valerte del método `entries()` del prototipo `Object`, que te devuelve un arreglo con *llaves* y *valores* que representan los miembros del objeto, comenzando por la propiedad `provincias` del objeto global.

Almacenando esos datos en un arreglo global, luego puedes utilizar esos mismo datos para ir actualizando los valores que se muestran en los select al usuario.

Sugiero también que utilices la API [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) para obtener los datos y ya no el viejo `XMLHttpRequest`.

Te dejo un ejemplo con provincias y cantones, en el que puedes basarte para ampliarlo hacia los distritos.

```js
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/josuenoel/80daca657b71bc1cfd95a4e27d547abe/raw/5c615419196ed40a3dbdff69cb3d9719b1d6bb1e/provincias_cantones_distritos_costa_rica.json';

let datosCR = {};
let provincias = [];

const selProvincia = document.getElementById("provincia");
const selCanton = document.getElementById("canton");

async function getCRData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Error al obtener datos");
  }
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  return jsonData;
}

async function obtenerDatos() {
  datosCR = await getCRData();
  let provObj = datosCR.provincias;
  for (const [kp, vp] of Object.entries(provObj)) {
    let opcion = document.createElement("option");
    opcion.text = vp.nombre;
    opcion.value = kp;
    selProvincia.add(opcion);
    
    let provincia = {id: kp, nombre: vp.nombre, cantones: []};
    let cantonObj = vp.cantones;
    for (const [kc, vc] of Object.entries(cantonObj)) {
      let canton = {id: kc, nombre: vc.nombre, distritos: []}
      provincia.cantones.push(canton);
    }
    provincias.push(provincia);
  }
}

function initSelCanton() {
  selCanton.innerHTML = "";
  let opcion = document.createElement("option");
  opcion.text = "Seleccione un cantón";
  selCanton.add(opcion);
}

function selProvinciaChange() {
  initSelCanton();
  let value = selProvincia.value;
  let prov = provincias.find(element => element.id == value);
  if (prov) {
    prov.cantones.forEach((canton) => {
      let opcion = document.createElement("option");
      opcion.text = canton.nombre;
      opcion.value = canton.id;
      selCanton.add(opcion);
    });
  }
}

function selCantonChange() {
  let pvalue = selProvincia.value;
  let cvalue = selCanton.value;
  let prov = provincias.find(element => element.id == pvalue);
  if (prov) {
    let canton = prov.cantones.find(element => element.id == cvalue);
    if (canton) {
      console.log("seleccion:", pvalue, cvalue, prov.nombre, canton.nombre);
    }
  }
}

obtenerDatos();
```

```html
<label for"provincia">Provincia</label>
<select id="provincia" onChange="selProvinciaChange()">
  <option value=none>Seleccione una provincia</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for"canton">Cantón</label>
<select id="canton" onChange="selCantonChange()">
  <option value=none>Seleccione un cantón</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido bastante. Si, me di cuenta de que no era muy iterable ese json investigando un poco más. Genere otro a partir de esos datos y cree otro javascript porque la idea es la de poner los nombres de las provincias, cantones y distritos en el value de cada opción para posteriormente meterlos en una BD. Pero aun así me quedo también con tu solución para estudiarla y comprenderla mejor. 

Nuevamente gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Si vos mismo lo estás publicando, si es mejor que devuelvas un JSON más amigable, por ejemplo como el que produzco yo como resultado del proceso en `ObtenerDatos`.